# Unable to access a service through a service name. in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I am new to Kubernetes and I'm experimenting with different things. This is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hellok8s
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hellok8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hellok8s
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: brianstorti/hellok8s:v3
        name: hellok8s-container
```

and below is my service file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hellok8s-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hellok8s
  ports:
  - port: 4567
    nodePort: 30001
```

I'm using the exec command and from inside the container, I'm trying to access the service using the service name. When I access this using the cluster IP, it works fine but when I try to access it using the service name it doesn't work. what might be the problem?

Comment: 1. have you tried appending namespace, such as `servicename.namespace` 2. seems you missed `protocol: TCP` in service

Comment: the service is running on TCP. i have checked the service. and how can I append the namespace? @ Lei Yang

Comment: but you didn't paste the `TCP` section of service, can you update question? i don't know from where you exec, if from anther namespace, you can call `hellok8s-svc.belongingnamespace`

Comment: i'm executing it from the default namespace

Comment: which port are you using when using svc? it should be 4567, not 30001

Comment: @nimramubashir, is your problem now resolved?

Comment: @Mikołaj Głodziak i have debugged deeper and there seems to be some problem with the internal pod-pod communication. I'm creating a cluster through kubeadm and there seems to be some problem with it that Is causing this problem. I'm asking a new question for that. I have tried deploying it on the cloud and this is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Posted as community wiki, to better visibility.
As [nimramubashir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14802233/nimramubashir) mentioned in the comment:

> I have debugged deeper and there seems to be some problem with the internal pod-pod communication. I'm creating a cluster through kubeadm and there seems to be some problem with it that Is causing this problem. I'm asking a new question for that. I have tried deploying it on the cloud and this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The service DNS: `hellok8s-svc.default.svc` is **only** accessible **inside** the cluster.

Service DNS: `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc`

Since you're using service of type `NodePort`, you will be able to access it at `NODE_IP:NODT_PORT` both from inside and outside of the cluster. But the service DNS address won't work from outside the cluster. This is the expected behavior.

**Update:**

While using `curl` with service DNS, make sure you're using the [complete DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) address:

- `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Try it from inside the container:

```sh
$ curl http://hellok8s-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:4567
```

**N.B.:**

Say, you don't remember the DNS naming format, you can still get the complete address by `nslookup` CLI.

```sh
# nslookup service-name.namespace
$ nslookup es-all.demo
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      es-all.demo
Address 1: 10.96.97.198 es-all.demo.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: 'I'm using the exec command and from inside the container --- the OP says that. it's from the service's container itself?

Comment: I'm using the exec command to enter the container. i'm able to access it using the cluster ip, but unable to acess it using it using the service name i.e., curl http://hellok8s-svc:4567

Comment: @nimramubashir I've updated the answer. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: is `cluster.local` a hardcoded string that never change?

Comment: @LeiYang `cluster.local` is the default cluster domain name, unless you have configured it to something else.

Comment: Thank you. I have figured out the problem. I was creating a cluster with kubeadm and there was some problem with the network cidr. After changing that, it is working as it is.

Comment: @nimramubashir what fix did you introduce?

Comment: @divine  as i was creating a cluster with kube adm, i was setting my network cidr to a customized ip. Changing it to 10.244.0.0/16 fixed the things for me.

Comment: @nimramubashir how did you figure out `10.244.0.0/16` is the correct CIDR? is `10.244.0.0/16` your vpc id?

Comment: @Kamol Hasan, I'm facing this error again. I have three different services one is react front-end, 2 django rest apis one is  running on port 8081 other on 8080. Both are type Cluster IP. When I'm curling one API  from the container of the other API, I'm getting failed to connect to localhost error. I'm lost at this point. Can you help?